# pip: Use version in requirements.txt to build wheels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip, requirements

I've got the following requirements.txt file:

```
matplotlib==3.4.2
numpy==1.22.4
```

and after installation (pip -r requirements.txt), if I execute `python -c "import matplotlib"` I got the following error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 26, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 82, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, cbook, scale
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/scale.py", line 18, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 179, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 46, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

from what I understood, when installing matplotlib, pip built a wheel using the version 1.23 of numpy. Then, when I execute my code, it find the version 1.22.4.

So, is there any way to use the versions provided in the requirements.txt file to build the wheels or any useful solution to this problem?

Edit: I need it working on Python 3.10 and I can't update numpy to 1.23 because I also use numba and the last version require numpy<1.23

Comment: That looks like a hard bug. Beyond monkey-patching (not-recommended), you may want to consider using an older version of both modules or python

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney The anaconda distribution will yield the same outcome for the same python version and package requirements as the problem is at the package level - it's not a dependency problem. Conda will help with dependencies and finding compatible runtime libraries for packages that require them, but is not equipped to solve a situation like this which only arises when the package is used

Comment: Aren't the requirements often just the packages the code was tested with? Also, isn't the stable version of numpy 1.23? 1.22.4 was a maintenance release.

Comment: @jrd1 My implication was more that the software would run in a stable environment without the need to explicitly have numpy 1.22.4 and matplotlib 3.4.2, since current versions of numpy are 1.23 and 3.5.2 respectively.

Comment: @jrd1 I created a conda environment with `conda create -n testing numpy=1.22.4 matplotlib=3.4.2 python`, which works without issue.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Using Python3.10 as the OP? Also, the install should work - did you try running the snippet the OP shared?

Comment: No. I let conda build the environment w/o specifying the python version; it install 3.9.12. However, the OP is using python3.10, but it's not stated as a requirement.

Comment: Also this question is likely a [duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+on+python+3.10+site%3Astackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1RXQR_enUS982US982&biw=1314&bih=1327&sxsrf=ALiCzsZpHV3elSZ8_P_dnLTp3SXpa9wG4A%3A1656443439558&ei=L1K7YpfPIarWkPIP6sqdqAU&ved=0ahUKEwjXorjW7ND4AhUqK0QIHWplB1UQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=matplotlib+on+python+3.10+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQ8BxY1CFg4iVoBXAAeACAAS6IAVuSAQEymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) of many other questions with matplotlib and python 3.10.

Comment: @jrd1 Yes, I successfully ran `python -c "import matplotlib"`

Comment: Yes it's a requirement for me to use Python 3.10. Also, I can't update to numpy 1.23 because I also need numba and the last version required numpy<1.23 (numpy 1.23 was released only one week ago so I could understand that all libs that use it are not updated yet)...

Also, I could manage to get it working by updating matplotlib to the last version. In this case, pip doesn't have to build a wheel (to be honest, I don't understand why...) but it's not a very nice solution because I have to retest all my code with this new version of matplotlib (and I got the same problem with scikit-learn)